# traverse json data / sibling data

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax, json

I currently have a json object, that I loop through and output a list of links.

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jasonday/hzZ8j/

each link is given an id based upon the storeID in the json.

What I want to do, is when a link is clicked it finds the id in the json, and then writes the sibling element "otherData" to #otherDataDiv

I've worked with traversing xml, but I'm not sure how to accomplish this with json.

Another user answered this question prior, which worked in a testing environment, but doesn't work on the site due to conflicts with the beta plugin - jquery.tmpl.js. I'd rather do this without a plugin. (jquery.tmpl.js version - http://jsfiddle.net/jasonday/RuEsj/)

(would xml be a preferred method here?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of re-traversing the JSON on each click, I'd take a different approach and just reduce some of that string concatenation, create elements directly, and use jQuery's `.data()` to associate the `"otherData"` of each item with the element:

```
function GenerateMarkup(states, className) {
    $('<ul>', {'class':className}).append($.map(states, function (v,i) {
       return $('<li>')
            .append($('<h3>',{text:v.stateName}))
            .append($.map(v.store, function (value, index) {
                return $('<a>',{href:value.storeURL,'class':'storeInactive',id:value.storeID, text:value.storeName})
                    .data('otherData',value.otherData)
                    .click(function(){
                        $('#otherDataDiv').text($(this).data('otherData'));
                        return false;
                    })[0];
            }))[0];

    })).appendTo('#storeList');
}
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/UQEJA/3/)**

Comment: I've got it working for my needs - thanks! Unsure of who gave you a downvote, I'd be interested in hearing why if that person cares to comment